# Insert hyphens between mongodb post title

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, express

I have an express app where users can make and on posts to view them. To do this I'm searching posts by the title.

The problem is that I am searching the posts by the post title. It works fine if the post title has no spaces but if the post title has spaces the page gives an error. My question is how can I insert hyphens into the spaces between the post title, kind of like how stack overflow does it. *ie. Insert hyphens-between-mongodb-post-title*

This is what finds the post by title.

```
let post = await Posts.find(req.params.postTitle).populate('user').lean();
```

I've tried to do something like:

```
let post = await Posts.find(req.params.postTitle).populate('user').lean();
post = post.replace(/\s+/g, "-"))
```

^ returns `post.replace was not a function`. Is there a way I can do it inside the mongodb find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to call the `replace` function on all the `post` documents.

You should instead use it on a single `post.title` only.

```
let post = await Posts.findOne(req.params.postTitle).populate('user').lean();
post.title = post.title.replace(/\s+/g, "-"));
await post.save();
```